# a while loop for printing multiple of 3

Tags: java

Your program should print the following:

```
 0 3 6 9 12 15 18 loop ended!
```

This is my code. May I know why can't I do the desired output?

```
int i = 0;

while(i%3 == 0 && i < 20 ) {
    System.out.print(i);
    i++;
}

System.out.print("loop ended!");
```

Comment: You `while()` already exists when the value for `i` becomes `1` (since the condition will be `false`).

Comment: You have to loop *while* `i` is less than 20 and print *if* it is divisible by 3. Hint hint...

Answer (score 3):

You have a condition in your while loop that must be satisfied for the while loop to continue running. When i increments to 1, the while loop condition fails and thus will stop running, so your program will only print 0. You instead should use an if statement inside the while loop with the mod condition:

```java
int i = 0;
while(i < 20) {
    if(i%3 == 0) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    i++;
}
System.out.print("loop ended!");
```

Comment: Why should i++ use outside the if statement?

Comment: Because regardless if i is divisible by 3 or not, you want to increment it for the next iteration of the while loop. For example, when i is 0, it will go into the if statement, print, and then increment i. When i is 1, it won't go in the if statement, but will still increment i. The if statement is just to take the values of i divisible by 3 and print them. Let me know if this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

`i % 3 == 0 && i < 20` - this condition evaluates to `false` when the value of `i` becomes 1. So loop only executes once.

You just need `i < 20` as a loop condition and in each iteration of the loop, just add 3 in `i`.

```
int i = 0;

while(i < 20) {
   System.out.print(i + " ");
   i += 3;
}

System.out.print("loop ended!");
```

**Output:**

```
0 3 6 9 12 15 18 loop ended!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int i = 0;

    do {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    } while ((i += 3) < 20);

    System.out.print("loop ended!");
}
```

---

I offer to simplify your code with usein `for` loop:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i += 3)
        System.out.print(i + " ");

    System.out.print("loop ended!");
}
```